# Click event listener inside a form

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add event listener to a button inside a form but for whatever reason it doesn't work the way I want it. When on the other hand I move the button out of the form it starts working.

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('a').style.background = 'red';
})
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('b').style.background = 'red';
})
```

```html
<form>
<button id="a">test</button>
</form>

<button id="b">test</button>
```

When I click the button inside the form it turns red for a fraction of second and then goes back to default style. Can someone explain me what causes this behaviour and suggest a solution?

Comment: add `type="button"` inside of form button

Comment: @GeorgeBailey thanks, that seems to be perfect solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default type of a button is `submit`. And that's the type of your buttons. And when you click a button with type `submit` inside a form it submits the form and you see the style reset. You can add `type="button"` in your button markups and check

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', () => {
 document.getElementById('a').style.background = 'red';
})
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', () => {
 document.getElementById('b').style.background = 'red';
})
```

```html
<form>
<button id="a" type="button">test</button>
</form>

<button id="b">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `preventDefault()`, or assign button type, `type="button/submit"`, if submit use `preventDefault()`, if button ignore it; default behaviour of button is submit if type not assigned.

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', () => {

 document.getElementById('a').style.background = 'red';
})
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById('b').style.background = 'red';
})
```

```html
<form>
<button type="button" id="a">test</button>
</form>

<button id="b">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use preventDefault() function which prevents form from reloading the page!

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById('a').style.background = 'red';
})
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', () => {
 document.getElementById('b').style.background = 'red';
})
```

```html
<form>
<button id="a">test</button>
</form>

<button id="b">test</button>
```